# Create a sharable area to reduce replicated import statements

Tags: java

All classes imports same libraries. Is it possible, for same package, create a share area? By this way, all classes on the same package can load same imports by loading share area. For example, In package FOO, all class have to import library A,B,C,D and F. Create a shared area like in windows so that all replication is reduced in all classes because they all import same libraries.

Is it possible to do ?

Comment: No, it's not possible in Java. You can use star form of import to reduce the no of imports but It's not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for already occurs automatically!

In writing your Java program, you use import statements to bring in class declarations (so syntax can be checked). The actual classes that are used are loaded by the class loader during execution (from libraries packaged with your java program).